# Scientific notation with three significant figures

Tags: objective-c, scientific-notation

Is there a way to use scientific notation in objective c and have it display three significant digits only? What I am current using is:

```
string = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%e", floatNumber];
// floatNumber = 100000; string = 1.000000e+06
```

I just want string = 1.00e+06

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the format specifier ".2" as follows:

```
    string = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.2e", floatNumber];
```

[From apple's documentation:](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/Strings/Articles/formatSpecifiers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004265-SW1)

> The format specifiers supported by the NSString formatting methods and CFString formatting functions follow the IEEE printf specification...

And from the [IEEE printf specification](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/printf.html), if you read under the Description section, you will find:

> e, E
>
> > The double argument shall be converted in the style "[-]d.ddde±dd", where there is one digit before the radix character (which is non-zero if the argument is non-zero) and the number of digits after it is equal to the precision; if the precision is missing, it shall be taken as 6; if the precision is zero and no '#' flag is present, no radix character shall appear. The low-order digit shall be rounded in an implementation-defined manner. The E conversion specifier shall produce a number with 'E' instead of 'e' introducing the exponent. The exponent shall always contain at least two digits. If the value is zero, the exponent shall be zero.